# JavaScript Fetch & Push Array returns “undefined”

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, fetch

I am writing an app in plain javascript. I'm having a problem in which when putting the 150 objects into array, some of the objects in the array are undefined.  When I console.log the object before they are pushed into array, they are fine and all 150 objects display.  But while I am pushing them to the array, some are undefined, and some do get pushed successfully.  My understanding is that it could be a timing of sequence issue where for some objects they may not have been fully fetched but the push to array already happens.  Is there a way to make sure they are sequenced so that the array gets pushed only after a fully successful fetch of the object?  Thanks for your help.

```js
const fetchPokemon = function () {

  const pokemons = [];

  for ( let i=1; i <= 150; i++) {
      const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
      fetch(url).then( res => { return res.json(); })
      .then( data => {
          const pokemon = {
              name: data.name,
              id: data.id          
          };
          pokemons.push(pokemon);
          console.log(pokemon);
          console.log(pokemons[i]);
      });
  }
};

fetchPokemon();
```

Output - Varies for different reload of the page in term of the undefined array elements

```
app.js:17 undefined
app.js:16 {name: "dragonite", id: 149}
app.js:17 undefined
app.js:16 {name: "mewtwo", id: 150}
app.js:17 undefined
app.js:16 {name: "kingler", id: 99}
app.js:17 {name: "electrode", id: 101}
app.js:16 {name: "aerodactyl", id: 142}
app.js:17 {name: "zapdos", id: 145}
app.js:16 {name: "dratini", id: 147}
app.js:17 {name: "kingler", id: 99}
```

Comment: I don't think it would be timing, you're using promises which should run when the fetch task finishes. You're making 150 independent calls to the pokemon api, do the pokemon exist for those ids maybe? Is there a route in which you can retrieve the list in one get instead of 150? That's a lot of calls to make

Comment: in pokemons[i], i would refer to the loop variable value at the time of execution of that line but the array might not have those many values fetched and pushed to yet. I would suggest not to rely on the `i` variable within the callback inside loop. a side note - take a look at async/await instead of callbacks.

Comment: to see what is being pushed into the array, you can do this `console.log(pokemons[pokemons.length-1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that while `fetch` is async for each individual request, you are returning before all 150 requests have completed. In the below, in the for loop, instead of chaining onto the request and pushing right away, you push the promise into the `requests` array. Then, after the loop, you return one single Promise that resolves once all 150 promises have been requested and pushed int the `pokemons` array.

```js
const fetchPokemon = function() {
  const pokemons = [];
  const requests = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    const prom = fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

    requests.push(prom);
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Promise.all(requests)
      .then((proms) =>
        proms.forEach((p) => pokemons.push({
          name: p.name,
          id: p.id
        }))
      )
      .then(() => resolve(pokemons));
  });
};

fetchPokemon().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer aprouja1.  Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @aprouja1,

For my ease of understanding, if I want to use function notation instead of arrow function, I am trying to break up your code into separate, smaller chunks:

const pokemons = [];
const fetchPokemon = function () {
  const requests = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    //const prom = fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());
    fetch(url)
    .then(function (r) {
      return r.json();
    })
    .then(function (data){
      requests.push(data);
    });
    //requests.push(prom);
  }

Comment: But I couldn't get the code to work, in the sense that when .json promise object are obtained, to be able to push it to the requests array.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here, as a simpler more concise and optimal example using async/await.
fetches in parallel, with the feature that it iterates the first sequential ready fetch responses.  ie: if the first 25 fetches finish, it will iterate the first 25 in order without waiting for the latter 125.

```js
const fetchPokemon = async function() {
  const pokemons = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`;
    const data = fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
                           .then( ({name, id}) => ({name, id}) );
    pokemons.push(data);
  }
  for await (const pokemon of pokemons) {
    console.log(pokemon);
  }
  // or if you need to use the index:
  for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
    console.log(await pokemon[i]);
  }
};

fetchPokemon();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer user120242.  Really appreciate it.